# CoreNLP in Python for coreference resolution

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to use CoreNLP in Python for coreference resolution? I have tried using the Stanford server and [this link](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python). But they don't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? The server certainly outputs coreference information; in the worst case, you can make POST requests to the server and parse the resulting JSON.

Comment: edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl

Comment: I get such kind of error while using the local server

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace, and the command you used to run the server? This sounds like a classpath issue, from not having the full corenlp jar in your classpath?

Comment: java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer [port] [timeout]

Comment: No, I mean the actual command you used on the command line, and if you have wildcards in there (-cp "*") the contents of the directory you're in. What version of CoreNLP are you using? What's the full stack trace? You need to provide enough information for someone to debug what might be wrong, and not just say "yes, that should work. It works for everyone else."

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to this. I am using version 3.7.0.  I don't know what a full stack trace is.